# Find unique value using a join that depends on the max of a date field in one table when the max is not unique in the first table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following two tables to reconcile.

Table 1 : t1

```
ID  Price   Date Adjusted
-------------------------
1   10  2011/01/01
2   5   2011/01/05
2   6   2011/05/05
```

Table 2 : t2

```
ID  Price   Date Adjusted
-------------------------
1   10  2011/01/01
2   5   2011/01/05
3   6   2011/05/05
```

Now t1 is a transactions table, i.e. for the same ID there can be numerous entries. Whereas t2 is a snapshot in which all ID's are unique. I need to get the last quoted price in t1 and reconcile this to the value captured in t2. This is how I went about it :

```
SELECT ID,MAX([Date Adjusted]) as LastDate
INTO t1temp
FROM t1
GROUP BY ID
```

The above creates a table containing IDs and the corresponding last date when an adjustment was made. The price is not pulled as this would create duplicates.

Then the next step is to join the tables :

```
SELECT a.*, b.Price as Price1
FROM t1temp LEFT JOIN t2 b
ON a.ID = b.ID and a.LastDate = b.EntryDate
```

which again creates duplicates.

I learned all of my SQL from you guys so I am hoping you can help a novice iron out this small dent.

Comment: Which DBMS are u using? Oracle, SQL Server, Mysql, Postgresql, etc..

Comment: Hi I am using SQL Server.

Comment: There is no need for the temp table.

Answer (score 1):

Move the `a.LastDate = b.EntryDate` to WHERE Clause.

```
SELECT a.*, b.Price as Price1
FROM t1temp a LEFT JOIN t2 b
ON a.ID = b.ID 
Where a.LastDate=b.EntryDate
```

When using Left or right joins , the ON predicate doesn't work as filtering criteria but as matching condition. This means if left join is used then all rows from left table will be returned even if the condition from ON predicate evaluates to false. This might be giving you duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your problem but it looks like you need simple queries

```
SELECT ID, Price, max(DateAdjusted) INTO @a, @b, @c FROM t1 where dateadjusted=(select max(dateadjusted) from t1);
SELECT @a as ID, @b as T1_PRICE, t2.Price as T2_PRICE FROM t2 WHERE t2.ID=@a;
```

Ugly but it should work. You might need to declare a,b,c in MS SQL. MySQL is fortunately more flexible with dynamic variables.
You can combine these two queries but it will become even uglier ;)

Comment: Hi Michal thanks but I still get a few duplicates, you are correct though having read my question again it appears I did not structure it properly, basically in t1 It is possible to get two prices occuring at the same date which happens to be the maximum of the dates for that ID...i,e. Duplicates are not an issue.

Comment: That's overly complex. No variables or temp tables are needed for this query.

Comment: Maybe you should use DISTINCT keyword to make sure to filter out duplicates?

Comment: Hi Michal, I found a link here on stack overflow that solved my problem, this amounted to just creating a query that will give me the last record for esach ID. Thanks Again :)

Comment: This is the query I had to run to create a table containing the last price/entry for each ID. runtime was less than a second for a table of >17M records :SELECT a.ID,a.Price,a.EntryDate
INTO ##Test
FROM t1 a LEFT JOIN t2 b
ON (a.ID b.ID and a.EntryDate < b.EntryDate)
WHERE b.EntryDate is null

Comment: Alternatively a much easier wasy to get the last record is as follows: add an ID to each record, this ID is linearly increasing then create a table where you group each by say p.id and for each p.id take the max of ID and grup by p.ID. Now the table that is created contains the last ID for each p.ID which corresponds to the last record...works wonderfully.